# change attribute of dynamic element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with some logic. After clicking the button creates a **div** element. 
I'm need to remove class from this element. I'm know, how add evens to dynamic elements, but can't find, how change attribute of dynamic element..

```
<div class="one two">it's a div</div>
$('.one').removeClass('two'); // doesn't work
```

may be i'm need some like this: ?

```
$(document).on(...)
```

It's not duplicate!!! it's defferend questions. I'm don't need events!

Comment: can you add your code in JSFIDDLE and share with us. It will be better help you.

Comment: If you are creating the element, perhaps the best solution is to have the logic at that stage and put in only the correct class - rather than putting both in and then later trying to remove one or the other.

Comment: i'm can't change source code, but i'm can add my code to page..

Comment: @KonstantinMokhov https://jsfiddle.net/eLden5je/

Comment: @julekgwa without events i'm can't solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `on` function:

```
$('parent-selector').on('event', 'element-selector', function () {
    //the event triggered
});
```

When you need a event to be captured for dynamic elements.

**For Eg:** If you need a click event then you need to use `on`

Comment: what the event i'm need to use? all i'm need - remove class... Or you porpose me add event to clicked button ?